# multiple ports, SSL issue

Tags: apache

I have been searching this for some time and couldn't get to a speicifc answer.
I have configured a sever in CentOS env, with the following configuration in my vhost.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /xyz/dir
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    CustomLog /var/log/xyz/access.log common
    ErrorLog /var/log/xyz/error.log
    <Directory /xyz/dir>
        Options +Includes +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -ExecCGI
        AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:83>
    DocumentRoot /abc/dir
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    CustomLog /var/log/abc/access.log common
    ErrorLog /var/log/abc/error.log
    <Directory /abc/dir>
        Options +Includes +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -ExecCGI
        AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

As you can see I have configured 2 sites on different ports with same ip. Now I am trying to configure ssl on both the sites, I want the http as well as https both activated simultaneously on both.

I did some search and configured it with ssl, and added the following :-

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+SSLv3
    SSLCACertificateFile /path-to-ca-bundle
    SSLCertificateFile /path-to-crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile path-to-key
    SSLVerifyClient none
    SSLVerifyDepth 10
    DocumentRoot /xyz/dir
    ServerName 1.1.1.1:80
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    CustomLog /var/log/xyz/access.log common
    ErrorLog /var/log/xyz/error.log
    <Directory /xyz/dir>
        Options +Includes +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -ExecCGI
        AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# Did the same for :83
```

Now this works fine when I hit

```
https://1.1.1.1/ --> points to xyz
http://1.1.1.1/ --> points to xyz

http://1.1.1.1:83/ --> points to abc
https://1.1.1.1:83/ --> throws ssl_error_rx_record_too_long error
```

The https on :83 is not working. Need help !

Also `https://1.1.1.1:80/ --> throws ssl_error_rx_record_too_long error`
On the contrary `https://1.1.1.1/ --> works just fine and points to xyz`

Comment: Your port (80) is being used for **HTTP** not **HTTPS** `https://1.1.1.1:80/`

Comment: And as you said above, your other port (83) is being used for **HTTP**  too, so `https://1.1.1.1:83/`  should in fact throw the error message as you mentioned!

Comment: @undone yes agree but didn't get the answer you are try to explain. Can you please explain.

Comment: As you can see, your Apache is using port 443 for SSL connections. What you need to do is assign different port to your new SSL server (like 444). (use Listen directive )

Comment: @undone ah, I think i am unable to explain the situation here, in nutshell it means 2 different products on 2 different port (83 & 80 respectively) with added https security. All configs are for apache only no other service is running. :) hope that heps making the scenario clear.

Comment: @undone thanks for the prompt reply though

Comment: I know what you want but you can't have two services on one port!

Comment: @undone thanks man that did helped me in figuring out the issue.Cheers